# Django Filter items with OneToOne relationship to Group of Users

Tags: sql, django

In Django, if I have a model such as a Building which is OneToOne related to a (Django Auth) Group containing users, how can I find all the buildings to User belongs to (maybe those are all the buildings the User works in)? Building is one to one with Group so building has a group foreign key field called 'group'.

I've tried

```
Building.objects.filter(group__contains=user)
Building.objects.filter(group_user_set__contains=user)
```

I'm getting no matches when there should be matches.

Answer (score 7):

Using `contains` is not the right choice since it searches for expression inside field (string) not within the set. Try using:

```
Buildings.objects.filter(group__user=user)
```

Comment: That works! Since a group contains multiple users, how can it have a field 'user' though?

Comment: From [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships): *'To refer to a "reverse" relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model.'*

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one to one relationship why not just return the groups?

```
result = []
u = User.objects.get(your user here)
for group in u.groups.all():
    result.append(group.whateverYourForeignKeyFieldIsCalled)
return result
```